# Permissions when mounting a network drive

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

My setup is pretty simple. I have 1 Ubuntu 20.04 box that I'd like to connect to a network share (and have write permissions).

My issue seems to be that I'm mounting as Root but trying to access the drive as my user.

My FSTAB file:

```
#NEW DOWN

//10.10.30.100/ndown /media/ndown cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.0 0 0
```

This mounts just fine, but the owner is Root:Root

As Root I can read/write to this shared drive, but as my normal users I cannot. If If I try to CHOWN I get permissions denied.

What do I need to do so that I can have my user add files to this network mount?

I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Read `man mount.cifs`, the `uid=`,`gid=`, and `forceuid` will help. You can find your UID and GID with `id`.

Comment: That worked, I added my uid= to the FSTAB and now I have access. Not sure how to mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man mount.cifs`, the `uid=`,`gid=`, and `forceuid` will help.

You can find your UID and GID with `id`.